# Simple approximation of Inverse Incomplete gamma function

Tags: math, statistics, approximation, gamma-function

How could one approximate Inverse [Incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) Г(s,x) by some simple analytical function f(s,Г)?
That means write something like x = f(s,Г) = 12*log(123.45*Г) + Г + 123.4^s .

(I need at least ideas or references.)

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior ?

Comment: I have to apologize. I wrote Incomplete gamma function but meant Inverse incomplete gamma function. I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that x = f(s,Г) with given s can be nicely approximated by x = p0*(1-Г)^p1*ln(Г*p2). At least it worked for me with s <= 15 in region 0.001 < Г < 0.999.

Here p0,p1,p2 - is constants, which are chosen by approximation of f(s,Г) after you have chosen s.

Comment: What are p0, p1 and p2 and why doesn't s appear in your expression?

Comment: because "with given s". p_i will depend on s.

Comment: I see. Do I understand correctly that the procedure for finding p0, p1, p2 is numerical/iterative so then this cannot be used as a 2D analytic approximation? Or can they be found as functions of s? Do you mind if I ask how you found this approximation? (I'm trying to find a rough analytic 2D approximation of the incomplete gamma function.)

Comment: @tennenrishin, I can't judge about 2D approximation. [But if you need limited amount of s's (which is integer) than you can do it obviously]. I used ROOT software: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the code in Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/igamma.html and see what they're using.

EDIT: They also have inverses: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/igamma_inv.html

Comment: Christ, everything is in boost

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good implementation in [Cephes](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/).  There's also a [D translation](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/internal/math/gammafunction.d) that I think fixes a few bugs in the Cephes version.

Comment: gammaIncompleteComplInv in "D translation" is implemented by numerical methods ("the routine performs up to 10 Newton iterations to find the root of incompleteGammaCompl(a,x) - p = 0." (c) ). I think this can't help me to find simple formula with 2-5 parameters.